# Redirecting to backend based on port

Tags: haproxy

I'm fairly new to HAProxy so just looking for a little direction here. Here's a log of the problem and the config for that as well. I'm trying to force specific destination ports to use a specific backend and it's not working.

```
Dec 18 18:49:34 localhost HAPLB[8405]: x.x.x.x:64725 [18/Dec/2014:18:49:27.157] 890_imappop_25 890_imappop_25-smtp/<NOSRV> -1/-1/7084 187 PR 225/35/35/0/3 0/0


backend 890_imappop_25-smtp
    balance roundrobin
    option redispatch
    stick-table type ip size 60k peers mypeers

    server filter1-mail 192.168.115.38:25 check
    server filter2-mail 192.168.115.39:25 check

listen 890_imappop_25
    bind 192.168.115.100:25
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option redispatch
    option tcplog
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 debug
    stick-table type ip size 60k peers mypeers

    acl smtp_25 dst_port 25
    acl smtp_225 dst_port 225
    acl smtp_587 dst_port 587

    use_backend 890_imappop_25-smtp if smtp_25
    use_backend 890_imappop_225-smtp if smtp_225
    use_backend 890_imappop_587-smtp if smtp_587

    server imappop1-mail 192.168.115.42:25 check
    server imappop2-mail 192.168.115.43:25 check
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to add `mode tcp` to the backend section, so in this case it was defaulting to HTTP which obviously SMTP doesn't know how to talk to. Can't believe I forgot that.

```
backend 890_imappop_25-smtp
    balance roundrobin
    mode tcp
    option redispatch
    stick-table type ip size 60k peers mypeers

    server filter1-mail 192.168.115.38:25 check
    server filter2-mail 192.168.115.39:25 check
```